# showing admob interstitial every x play unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am trying to make my interstitial admob ad appear when a user enters the map for the third time.
My code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class interstitial_ad : MonoBehaviour {

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    void Start()
    {
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd ("ca-app-pub-xxx");
        interstitial.LoadAd (new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ());
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitial.Show();
        }    
    }
}
```

It shows the ad every time I enter the map, so I tried to add:

```
playCount++;
        if (playCount % 3 == 0) {
```

but that did not work for me, probably because of the void Update() part. Do you have any ideas/hints how to make it work?

Comment: Where did you add the `playCount++;` line?

Comment: playCount has to be stored in some GameManager class as a static for example, so you will be able to acces it as GameManager.playCount. If you put it in the same script as a interstitial it is zeroed every time you load the scene.

Comment: thanks for the replies, my current code that unfortunately doesn't display ads:
`public class interstitial_ad : MonoBehaviour {
 
 private InterstitialAd interstitial;
 private static int playCount = 0;

 void Start()
 {
  interstitial = new InterstitialAd ("ca-app-pub-xxx");
  interstitial.LoadAd (new AdRequest.Builder ().Build ());
 }
 void Update()
 {
  playCount++;
  if (playCount % 3 == 0) {
  if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
  {
   interstitial.Show();
  }    
 }
}`

Comment: Dude, `Update()` is called on every frame, so your `playCount++` happens 60 times per second, this should overflow you with ads, or API probably stops processing your requests at all.